# Getting each value from a list and iterate in data frame to sum up number values in a column with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

This is the list values i want to use to iterate in dataframe named df

```
np_checkList = np.array(['ALPHA', 'BETA', 'CHARLIE','DELTA'])
```

This is the dataframe I want to loop using the values in np_checklist against the column 'NAME'

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['ALPHA',2,'BUY'],
                            ['BETA',5,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',3,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',5,'BUY'],
                            ['DELTA',11,'BUY'],
                            ['ALPHA', 2,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',8,'SELL']]),
                   columns=['NAME','AMOUNT','Type'])
```

This is the data frame I want to achieve

```
     pd.DataFrame(np.array([['ALPHA',2,'BUY',' '],
                            ['BETA',5,'BUY',' '],
                            ['CHARLIE',3,'BUY','yes'],
                            ['CHARLIE',5,'BUY', 'yes'],
                            ['DELTA',11,'BUY',' '],
                            ['ALPHA', 2,'BUY',' '],
                            ['CHARLIE',8,'SELL','yes']]),
                         columns=['NAME','AMOUNT','TYPE','REMOVE'])
```

I sum up AMOUNT for column TYPE = 'BUY' and NAME = 'CHARLIE'. The result is 8.
Next, I sum up AMOUNT for column TYPE = 'SELL' and NAME = 'CHARLIE' The result is 8.

Since both results are equal, then a new column 'REMOVE' is created and a new value 'yes' is appended to the existing data row where NAME column is 'CHARLIE'.

As for the rest of the names, since the BUY and SELL total sums are not equal, the column is null.

I tried to write my code below but I received error: *The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

```
for name in np_checkList:
    if (df['NAME']==name) & (df['TYPE']=='BUY'):
        totalBUY = totalBUY + df['AMOUNT']
        
    if (df['NAME']==name) & (df['TYPE']=='SELL'):
        totalSELL = totalBUY + df['AMOUNT']
```

I see I cannot use my old school Java or C way of coding to iterate in Python. May I get some advice from python users here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
np_checkList = np.array(['ALPHA', 'BETA', 'CHARLIE','DELTA'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['ALPHA',2,'BUY'],
                            ['BETA',5,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',3,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',5,'BUY'],
                            ['DELTA',11,'BUY'],
                            ['ALPHA', 2,'BUY'],
                            ['CHARLIE',8,'SELL']]),
                   columns=['NAME','AMOUNT','Type'])

df['REMOVE'] = ''

for name in np_checkList:

    iby = np.where((df['NAME'] == name) & (df['Type'] == 'BUY'))
    totalBUY = ((df.iloc[iby].AMOUNT).astype(int)).sum()

    isl = np.where((df['NAME'] == name) & (df['Type'] == 'SELL'))
    totalSELL = ((df.iloc[isl].AMOUNT).astype(int)).sum()

    if totalBUY == totalSELL:
        df.REMOVE.iloc[iby] = 'yes'
        df.REMOVE.iloc[isl] = 'yes'

    
df
```

output:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the code, the verbosity allows me to understand how it is working

Answer (score 2):

NB. comparison of the answers. On the provided dataset: @mozway: 2.22ms, @HenryYik: 5.26ms, @Corralien: 6.88ms ; on a 10,000 times larger dataframe: @mozway: 3.32ms, @HenryYik: 5.03ms, @Corralien: 7.39ms

Here is a working pipeline. Negate the values of "AMOUNT" if "Type" == "SELL", calculate the sum grouped per "NAME". If sum is 0, then keep the "BUY", remove the "SELL".

To annotate:

```
df['REMOVE'] = (df.assign(AMOUNT2=df['AMOUNT'].mul(df['Type'].eq('BUY').mul(2).sub(1)))
                  .groupby(['NAME'])
                  ['AMOUNT2'].transform('sum').eq(0)
               ).map({True: 'yes', False: ''})
```

output:

```
      NAME  AMOUNT  Type REMOVE
0    ALPHA       2   BUY       
1     BETA       5   BUY       
2  CHARLIE       3   BUY    yes
3  CHARLIE       5   BUY    yes
4    DELTA      11   BUY       
5    ALPHA       2   BUY       
6  CHARLIE       8  SELL    yes
```

To remove directly:

```
df[(df.assign(AMOUNT2=df['AMOUNT'].mul(df['Type'].eq('BUY').mul(2).sub(1)))
      .groupby(['NAME'])
      ['AMOUNT2'].transform('sum').ne(0)
     |(df['Type'].eq('BUY'))
   )]
```

output:

```
      NAME  AMOUNT Type
0    ALPHA       2  BUY
1     BETA       5  BUY
2  CHARLIE       3  BUY
3  CHARLIE       5  BUY
4    DELTA      11  BUY
5    ALPHA       2  BUY
```

Finally, you can check if your "NAME"s are in the "np_checkList" using: `df.query('NAME in @np_checkList')`

Comment: try to not use comparison between answers because there is a new answer and I updated mine. This can be confused for the OP. Especially since my solution is faster than yours :-) lol.

Comment: @Corralien your new solution is more of less mine, using where instead of the *2-1 trick ;)

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDabas I added this at the end

Comment: Thanks @mozway. Nice answer and I am now reading python docs on each api call to understand the entire structure of the code. I tried the 1st set of codes  (the codes under 'To annotation') but I get all empty values for CHARLIE at 'REMOVE' column.

Comment: Ignore my comment. I know what happen. I have to change the AMOUNT column to numeric first before running the 1st set of codes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can `groupby` on `Name` and `Type`, get the result then check whether the difference of buy and sell equals to 0:

```
s = (df.loc[df["NAME"].isin(np_checkList)]
       .groupby(["NAME", "Type"], as_index=False)["AMOUNT"].sum())

names = s.loc[s.groupby("NAME")["AMOUNT"].diff().eq(0), "NAME"]

df["REMOVE"] = np.where(df["NAME"].isin(names), "YES", "")

print (df)

      NAME  AMOUNT  TYPE REMOVE
0    ALPHA       2   BUY       
1     BETA       5   BUY       
2  CHARLIE       3   BUY    YES
3  CHARLIE       5   BUY    YES
4    DELTA      11   BUY       
5    ALPHA       2   BUY       
6  CHARLIE       8  SELL    YES
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks @Henry Yik

Answer (score 1):

Compute balance between `BUY` and `SELL` and flag all rows where the balance is 0:

```
def balance(sr):
    return sr.loc[sr['Type'] == 'BUY', 'AMOUNT'].astype(int).sum() \
           - sr.loc[sr['Type'] == 'SELL', 'AMOUNT'].astype(int).sum()

out = df.merge(df.groupby('NAME')
                 .apply(balance)
                 .eq(0)
                 .rename('REMOVE')
                 .replace({True: 'yes', False: ''}),
               on='NAME', how='left')
```

```
>>> out
      NAME  AMOUNT  Type REMOVE
0    ALPHA       2   BUY
1     BETA       5   BUY
2  CHARLIE       3   BUY    yes
3  CHARLIE       5   BUY    yes
4    DELTA      11   BUY
5    ALPHA       2   BUY
6  CHARLIE       8  SELL    yes
```

A faster solution:

```
df['REMOVE'] = df.assign(AMOUNT=np.where(df['Type'] == 'SELL', 
                                         df['AMOUNT'].astype(int)*-1,
                                         df['AMOUNT'].astype(int))) \
                 .groupby('NAME')['AMOUNT'] \
                 .transform(sum).eq(0).replace({True: 'yes', False: ''})
```

Comment: Nice solution but maybe also check if the 'NAME' isin np_checkList since  OP has an array of values

Comment: @Corralien, thanks. The function solution works after i added in astype(int) before .sum() to resolve this error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'. I tried the faster solution as well but CHARLIE does not have 'yes' under the REMOVE column. Wondering why is that so.

Comment: @Corralien, i found the answer, Have to change the AMOUNT column to numeric first, Thanks for the code.

Comment: I updated my answer to fix the problem of `AMOUNT` dtype. `AMOUNT` is `str` because you create your dataframe with `np.array` which it's not a good idea. Do you really need `np_checkList`?

Comment: With your solution, I also realized I do not need *np_checkList*. My initial thought is to run through the entire table, I need to use iteration row by row and I need start and end values to start the loop running.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe:**

```
# 'SELL' values to negative
df.loc[df['TYPE']=='SELL', 'AMOUNT'] *=-1

print(df[df.groupby('NAME')['AMOUNT'].transform(sum) != 0])

    NAME  AMOUNT TYPE
0  ALPHA       2  BUY
1   BETA       5  BUY
4  DELTA      11  BUY
5  ALPHA       2  BUY
```